# jQuery to add a class to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where if a Div called 'VALID_VAR_264' contains the word 'Required' then the class 'sponz' is added to the div.

However, how can I adapt this so that if the Div called 'VALID_VAR_264' contains 'Required' then I can get it to add the class 'sponz' to a different div.

Is this possible?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery('#VALID_VAR_264:contains("Required")').addClass('sponz')
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the length of the jQuery object and if it is greater than 0 execute the code you need to:

```
if(jQuery('#VALID_VAR_264:contains("Required")').length>0) 
{
    $(otherSelector).addClass('sponz');
}
```

Comment: Also, instead of referencing text within a div, is it possible to do this if a class is present within a div

Comment: @Jumbomills - `if ( $('#elem').hasClass('something') ) { ...`

Comment: Certainly. You can either combine your selector or use the find function jQuery('#VALID_VAR_264 .someClass') or jQuery('#VALID_VAR_264').find('.someClass')